# jQuery : Hover on img to change img and text

Tags: jquery, html

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

When a user hovers over one of the smaller images:

- That smaller image + text should replace the large image + text.
- When the user isn't hovering; return large set to its original image
  and text.

This is what I have so far. It isn't doing the job. So how would I go about making this work? What Am I doing wrong?

```
$('.small-news').hover(function() {
    var hover_img = $(this).children('img').prop('src');
    var hover_p = $(this).children().find('p').text();
    $("#main").children('img').attr('src', hover_src);
    $("#main").children().find('#title').text(hover_p);
});
```

I made a **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eSJL8/12/)** to help show you what I'm working with. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: hover_src is not defined `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Cache the main element
var $main = $("#main");
var org_img = $main.find('img').prop('src');
var org_title = $main.find('.title').text();

$('.small-news').hover(function () {
    var hover_img = $(this).find('img').prop('src');
    var hover_p = $(this).find('p').text();
    $main.find('img').prop('src', hover_img);
    $main.find('.title').text(hover_p);
}, function () {
    $main.find('img').prop('src', org_img);
    $main.find('.title').text(org_title);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga9AY/)

Answer (score 1):

Too many small errors to list individually. Check this against your original:

```
$('.small-news').hover(function () {
    var hover_img = $(this).find('img').prop('src');
    var hover_p = $(this).find('p').text();
    $("#main").find('img').prop('src', hover_img);
    $("#main").find('.title').text(hover_p);
}, function () {
    $("#main").find('img').prop('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-525-525-7.jpg');
    $("#main").find('.title').text('Google Glass has new rival in GlassUp smart specs');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eSJL8/21/)**